# Esp8266 measuring time between deep sleeps

Tags: time, arduino, esp8266, sleep-mode, real-time-clock

I'm using a Nodemcu Esp8266 v1.0 to measure some data and sending it with WiFi. I'm programming it with the Arduino library.

In order to save battery, I use Deep Sleep. Some of the measurements use interruptions to wake-up the device BEFORE the time implemented in the function:

```
ESP.deepSleep(20e6); // 30e6 is 30 seconds
```

So, to keep a consistent frequency of updating the data, I would need to know the time between Deep Sleeps. Do you know any function or memory direction to know how much time RTc counted? I could use EEPROM, but I would need where can I measure the time.

Comment: there'a a reset reason provided, so you can tell if the full time has elapsed or not. if it's not fully elapsed, you need an external ref to tell "what time is it?", like NTC or RTC

Comment: Could exist a way to access the internal RTC? I know that is imprecise, but fair enough for what I'm doing. The internal RTC is the only thing that is working while Deep Sleeps